# config.groovy meare with .property file in grails

Tags: grails, configuration, dependency-properties, config, configuration-files

In my config.groovy i have set ..

`emailTo="admin@xzyz.com"
emailForm="notification@oabc.com"`

but i want some flexibility in this. Can I change this while my project is running form property file ? Please help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `.property` file as well, by default Grails looks for properties at:

- in calss path `${appName}-config.properties`
- and global config `~/.grails/${appName}-config.properties`
- path passed as a system vaiable named `${appName}.config.location`

Just take a look at first few lines of your `Config.groovy`, you can put there any other path to your own .properties

See also http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/conf.html#configExternalized

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a plugin to support dynamic reloading of external config files whenever they change, but conceptually if this is data that is supposed to be modifiable at runtime then maybe it would be better to represent it as a domain object and store it in the database.

I use this method on a number of projects, defining a domain class

```
class AppConfiguration {
  String adminEmail
  String appTitle
  // etc
}
```

and ensuring there is always exactly one instance in the database, creating an initial instance in `BootStrap` if it is not already present. Now anywhere in the app that requires this config data I just do `AppConfiguration.list()[0]`

I just use dynamic scaffolding for the edit pages, which are restricted to be accessible only to admin users through Spring Security.